# Google Analytics API and UI Report Users data not matching

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, talend

I've extensively searched in forum and after that putting this question so that someone might be able to help me.

**Scenario:**

In Google analytics dashboard, we have created logical categories based on keywords within `PagePath`. For instance, if my PagePath contains keyword `\sports\` we call it Sports Section category.

We capture the User count weekly from UI as shown below :
[image: imgae1]

I am now trying to move this data in MySQL db using `Talend Open Studio Data Integration`.
I am using a component`tgoogleanalyticsinput` where I can feed Dimensions and Metrics.

**Problem:**
I analyzed 2 days of data and found the following observation:

```
Date     All User   Sports  Auto     
01-Jun  2220088   325174    51825   (visible in image chart) 
02-Jun  2950015   256390    80472   (not visible in above chart) 
Total   5170103   581564    132297  (sum of above)
API :   5170103   581564    132297  (received from API)
UI :    4910532   553400    129652  (shown in UI)
```

So, the data on chart matches with what I'm getting from API BUT they both do not match with what is shown in UI number.

**I visited [this link](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-users/) to understand what those numbers mean on Google UI**.
Problem is, what dimension and metrics should I take so that my API values matches with UI number?
I tried to take `ga:PagePath, ga:Date` as dimension and `ga:Users, ga:pageViews` as metrics but they're not working for me.

Comment: How do u get API total user number? Because creating one single query for a period of 2 days (1-2 June) should give you also 4 910 532 users (just like in UI). Simple manually summing users in X days period (day by day) will give you incorrect result (maybe you're making 2 single requests [one per a day]?)

Comment: @JacekSzymański : that's right. simple addition isn't working. UI count considers only 1 request as user if I'm making 2 single requests. Resolution is, to take user metrics without any dimension, over given time period and segment.